# Remove HTML Entity if Incomplete

Tags: php, html

I have an issue where I have displayed up to 400 characters of a string that is pulled from the database, however, this string is required to contain HTML Entities.

By chance, the client has created the string to have the 400th character to sit right in the middle of a closing P tag, thus killing the tag, resulting in other errors for code after it.

I would prefer this closing P tag to be removed entirely as I have a "...read more" link attached to the end which would look cleaner if attached to the existing paragraph.

What would be the best approach for this to cover all HTML Entity issues?  Is there a PHP function that will automatically close off/remove any erroneous HTML tags?  I don't need a coded answer, just a direction will help greatly.

Thanks.

Comment: this will sound silly, but the best approach would be to do input validation and reject input that's over 400 characters long so this doesn't happen in the first place. If the client can input something that your code cannot deal with, prevent that from happening.

Comment: Do you need any HTML in the strings? If not, perhaps you could strip_tags http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php EDIT: You could use this in combination with a find/if to get an alternative result which would not strip_tags unless [condition].

Comment: Just removing the damaged closing tag won't help much: you'd still have the opening tag open. What about any containing tags whose closing tag might also have been lost? Consider whether to attempt to reconstruct the missing tags, or strip the malformed ones altogether. This is not an easy problem, and no - I don't have an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the 400 characters are only a snippet of the full article, which is linked to via the "...read more" string I mentioned.  
The full article does require HTML tags, but if there is no other solution I guess I can strip them for the 400 character snippet.

Comment: redditor@ strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.
advermark@ as I understand your issue, all you need is to remove last broken tag and then strip_tags

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way you can do it with DOMDocument, its not perfect but it may be of interest:

```
<?php 
function html_tidy($src){
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $x = new DOMDocument;
    $x->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />'.$src);
    $x->formatOutput = true;
    $ret = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|body|head))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $x->saveHTML());
    return trim(str_replace('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">','',$ret));
}

$brokenHTML[] = "<p><span>This is some broken html</spa";
$brokenHTML[] = "<poken html</spa";
$brokenHTML[] = "<p><span>This is some broken html</spa</p>";

/*
<p><span>This is some broken html</span></p>
<poken html></poken>
<p><span>This is some broken html</span></p>
*/
foreach($brokenHTML as $test){
    echo html_tidy($test);
}

?>
```

Though take note of `Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans`'s comment.

Comment: Wow! This really works! It saved me from pulling out my hair all night. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Imtiaz np, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

why you don't take the last word in the paragraph or content and remove it, if the word is complete you remove it , if is not complete you also remove it, and you are sure that the content still clean, i show you an example for what code will be look like :

```
while($row = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ){
  //extract 400 first characters from the content you need to show
  $extraction = substr($row->text, 0, 400);
  // find the last space in this extraction
  $last_space = strrpos($extraction, ' ');
  //take content from the first character to the last space and add (...)
  echo substr($extraction, 0, $last_space) . ' ...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove last broken tag and then strip_tags

```
$str = "<p>this is how we do</p";
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, "<"));
$str = strip_tags($str);
```

Comment: This is fine if you trust the user input - but one could add a property to a HTML tag that contains a value and if there's a < sign within that value, like title="I am <evil" , you'll find that and keep the incomplete tag.