# Remove broken html tags from data in php

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am working on php app , where i got random text from different source like (email,db ect).Now I am facing a problem .I have text that contain broken HTML element like

```
$purl  ='FTP details are as 
follow:User name : Mahmud
div>password :1234556Than
ks ';
```

.I tried strip_tags and some preg matching algo's but didn't work.How can i remove the HTML elements if its not complete like in above `div>` tag.I know this type question asked earlier but i didn't know how can i do it.Thanks for any help.

For further details i am adding this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584244/fetch-new-message-without-replay-from-email-in-php).I am fetching emails and then getting specific portion of emails using DOM.

Comment: Is there a pattern for those broken html elements?

Comment: @AliTrixx No this time i got div> other it may be something else.I want to remove if any such type broken HTML occur in text.Thanks

Comment: Since there is no pattern or no way to find out if they will occur or not, you should fill an array with whatever broken tags you come up with then use str_replace to replace them all

Comment: Given the range of possible errors that could occur, you're going to have a hard time getting this right -- Even web browsers can have trouble sometimes when given broken HTML, and they're designed specifically to be able to handle it.

Comment: @Spudley i edit my question and add my previous question link.From there i got messages then i render that text.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.parsestring.php



<?php
ob_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>error<br>another line</i>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$config = array('indent' => TRUE,
        'output-xhtml' => TRUE,
        'wrap' => 200);

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($buffer, $config, 'UTF8');

$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;

?>
```

Comment: You also need to add the option `'show-body-only' => true` because it just an html fragment. See more on the options here: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Answer (score 0):

How about I'm an user and I want my username to be `<span man`?

You can't actually know when the text should be "corrected" because its a broken tag or when it's not.

You should just do something on your input. Are you getting this text from a curl output? But anyways, as I said, just check your reading input.

Comment: I am fetching emails this time , And after rendering i got some time like above .If you want to know about that code i can share that too.thanks

Comment: @AmalMurali Go ahead and develop an app which doesn't care about absolutely ALL inputs. Publish it and keep your telephone close.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I'm so sure that you are not doing the fetching correctly. Place the code and we can check it and try to improve it.

Comment: I think if i post that code the question will goes longer. Can you concentrate on that point that text can contain broken html elements.I think i have to store that broken elements in array then match that to text.

Answer (score 0):

You need HTML TIDY installed and configured in your php for details on this refer to this link

php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

And this question has been asked earlier, refer to this link for code (answer)

[Remove HTML Entity if Incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181660/remove-html-entity-if-incomplete)

Comment: thanks for your response.I visit that question before posting of my question.I can't restrict user on data entry time as i am fetching not saving data.

Comment: no need to restrict user, use HTML TIDY before displaying the text .